# Как корректно добавить в буфер обмена директорию с поддиректориями и файлами?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Попробовал такой метод:

```
// Set folder to clipboard
var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TestFolder");
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Но он не сработал.

Answer (score 0):

```
var col = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
{
    @"C:\Temp\1\",
    @"C:\Temp\2\"
};
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(col);
var paths = Clipboard.GetFileDropList().OfType<string>();
```